# Diffie-Hellman in swift can work with JAVA

Tags: java, swift4, diffie-hellman, public-key-exchange

I am trying to develop key-exchange Diffie-Hellman between a Swift and a Java server .
I read all link about Diffie-Hellman and in all of them told I should use `(g^a mod p)^b mod p = g^ab mod p` for making PublicKey.

But when I started to share my PublicKey with server I faced with this exception

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Inappropriate key specification
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(DHKeyFactory.java:85)
  at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)
  at com.pushro.server.managers.server.RequestsHandler.processKeyExchange(RequestsHandler.java:867)
  at com.pushro.server.managers.server.RequestsHandler.processPacket(RequestsHandler.java:275)
  at com.pushro.server.managers.server.RequestsHandler.processPacket(RequestsHandler.java:1315)
  at com.pushro.server.managers.server.RequestsHandler.access$000(RequestsHandler.java:40)
  at com.pushro.server.managers.server.RequestsHandler$1.handleEvent(RequestsHandler.java:96)
  at com.pushro.server.managers.queue.DisruptorManager$WriteEventHandler.onEvent(DisruptorManager.java:37)
  at com.pushro.server.managers.queue.DisruptorManager$WriteEventHandler.onEvent(DisruptorManager.java:34)
  at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:129)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key format
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHPublicKey.<init>(DHPublicKey.java:127)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(DHKeyFactory.java:78)
  ... 10 more
```

I used standard X509EncodedKeySpec for get key and generate Secret code in java.

```
X509EncodedKeySpec ks = new X509EncodedKeySpec(PublicKey_byte);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");
PublicKey clientPublicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(ks);
```

I've read all of this link but they didn't help me.

- https://github.com/gsurma/diffie_hellman_key_exchange
- https://gist.github.com/jmcd/b9a212df5dfa88b6d8dcb52c51b6be6b
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1643701-seckeycreatewithdata
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/seckey
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secure_transport#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000155

Comment: I have this issue too